# Most likely time car reachs maximum and minimum speed

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Assuming the acceleration of a car behaves like a normal distribution, wich we dont know the mean nor the std deviation: at minute 0 a car is driving at 50 km/h and at minute 10 his velocity is 60 km/h, I know the maximum velocity the car reached during that period is 80 km/h and the minimum velocity is 40km/h.

I want to estimate the most likely time the car reached its maximum and minimum velocity, how do I do it? Wich probability distribution would fit best?

Thank you in advance!

The problem is tricky because the minimum and maximum velocity are somehow dependant on each other, dont you agree?

Comment: (Having just been stuck in traffic, I can report that the trip’s minimum speed can happen whenever.) We’re going to need a lot more information. I can think of many completely plausible ways for speed to go. I’m not even sure that I see this as a statistics problem.

Comment: Lets assume the change in velocity of the car overtime behaves like a normal distribution, wich we dont know the average nor the std deviation. Instead of a car we could just as well be estimating the most likely time a river reached its maximum and lowest height

Comment: In what sense does the change in velocity "behave like a normal distribution?" This sounds like a description of Brownian motion, not automobile traffic.

Comment: In the sense that the acceleration of the car at any given point is independant from any previous acceleration, it is to make things simpler, Im trying to simulate this problem on python using random walks. Even if we consider the acceleration is actually dependant I dont believe the estimation would be different as we dont have the initial nor the end acceleration to begin with